# How to use rails validation for attribute provided dynamically from associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have `User` model having db fields as field1 to field10 and one of them is email field.

I want to validate it like below,

```
validates :field1,
          format: { .. },
          if: Proc.new{ |i| i.active? }
```

But my problem is, I do not know which is email field and it depends upon `UserStructure` object having db field as `email_field` which suggest which is email field in `User` table

```
validates Proc.new{ |i| i.user_structure.email_field },
          format: { .. },
          if: Proc.new{ |i| i.active? }
```

But above does not work and self will be always User class (when loading validation for  User class)

Please correct me or suggest if any alternative is there.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me. Having 10 database fields named `field1` to `field10`, where you don't know what each field actually represents, seems like a terrible design to me!! I would focus on figuring out how to get your unstructured data into some sort of known structure for the database.

Comment: Even if you can get this validation to work, how do you expect to "find user by email" in the future? Query all 10 fields of all records?!

Comment: @TomLord Yea, not terrible design but advanced. Client have access to user structure and he define which field is what like whether textbox or select list or is it email field text. Client have many users which provide data in form in described sturcture. So you can say our client is defining it. It works great indeed.

Comment: @TomLord "find user by email" will be illustrated as `find_by(email_field => 'abc@example.com')`

Comment: In my opinion, this isn't an advanced design, it's a bad design. Again, how do you plan to search for users by email **in the whole table** -- not only scoped to the records that one client defined?? A much better idea would be to abstract this client field mapping into a different table, and leave the users table in a well-define structure.

Comment: Something fundamental like an `email` field should be a dedicated column. For fuzzy "additional data" fields, you could just store it in a single JSON field. This also pre-emptively solves the problem: "What happens when a client wants to add an 11th field?".

Comment: ...Or, perhaps, this entire abstraction is actually unnecessary - and it's actually more practical to define multiple tables for the `user` data. (At the extreme, maybe even one table per client?!) YMMV. There's no silver bullet here, but if you're just storing `field1`...`field10`, you might as well use NoSQL instead.

Comment: @TomLord Client requirement was about 10 fields where he wanted to define which field will be email field. It was requirement so I could not help about it. And case to search users by email field, email is unique field, I added custom uniqueness validation and for format I asked question above here (as I do not want to go for custom for both). Finding user by email is quite easy by custom method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [custom validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validate :user_email_should_be_valid

  def user_email_should_be_valid
    email_field = user_structure.email_field
    email = send(email_field)

    if active? && !email.match?(EMAIL_REGEXP)
      errors.add(email_field.to_sym, "should be a valid email address")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I had used same thing as custom validations before solve most of problems but I want to use rails defined validation, but still thanks :)